# How do i add discord syntax to an embed?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the bots response to be in discord syntax but it ends up coming out like i type it.
`embed.add_field(name="$ping", value="'Responds with the bots latency.'", inline=False)`
i want the response to show like this `Responds with the bots latency.` but it shows up with the `s

Comment: Shouldn't you be using backticks instead of single quotation marks?

Comment: @KlausD. Your right..... im dumb sorry for wasting your time, i just started learning this last night.

Comment: @ParrotSec03 Don't be so hard on yourself. We are all learning.